# Batch Loop and Text file read

Tags: loops, batch-file

i am looking into making a simple bath file that will loop through few simple commands about 1200 times (length of text file).  My caveat comes in where those commands need a variable read in from a text file

Lets see if this pseudo code makes sense to anyone

```
start loop (for # of lines in txt file)
    net use \\"IP from txt file" /user:Username *
    robocopy \\server\share\path \\"IP from txt file"\c$\Folder
    robocopy \\server\share\path \\"IP from txt file"\c$\AnotherFolder
    net use \\"IP from txt file" /delete
loop
```

because of the environment and transferring of files from a domain server to a workgroup pc, this is about the only way i have found i can make this work.  For reasons entirely too long to type here i am unable to use psexec and its list function for this unfortunately.

Any help you might be able to provide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this batch file and if the output is correct remove each `echo` before your commands :

```bat
@echo off
set "File=List.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%File%"') do (
    echo net use \\%%A /user:Username *
    echo robocopy \\server\share\path \\%%A\c$\Folder
    echo robocopy \\server\share\path \\%%A\c$\AnotherFolder
    echo net use \\%%A /delete
)
pause
```

***EDIT : To save the result into a LogFile***

```bat
@echo off
set "File=List.txt"
set "LogFile=LogFile.txt"
If Exist "%LogFile%" Del "%LogFile%"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('Type "%File%"') do (
    echo net use \\%%A /user:Username *
    echo robocopy \\server\share\path \\%%A\c$\Folder
    echo robocopy \\server\share\path \\%%A\c$\AnotherFolder
    echo net use \\%%A /delete
)>>"%LogFile%"
Start "" "%LogFile%" 2>&1
```

Comment: fantastic - works exceptionally well

Now for one more newb question - how might i append all this to a log file somewhere - the location of which can be whatever is convenient

Comment: @Dashwitz Did you mean that you want to save the result into a LogFile ?

Comment: correct, i tried redirecting the output to >logfile.txt but that does not produce the desired result.  What would be ideal would be to not only have the output visible in the cmd prompt - but also save to a log file

Comment: That works great! better than the option i was working on - putting it in a sub and writing the output of the sub.  Thanks again

Comment: crazy followup here, but is it possible to "multithread" this? as you can see, i am moving some files between a domain server and a couple locations on remote workgroup machines (3800 or so machines) and i am coming no where close to utilizing the available bandwidth.  if i could send to as many as 4 machine at once, i should be able to bring down the transfer time significantly